# Creating a new column in SQL Oracle with a subquery - any suggestions?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have the columns `Yearmonth`, `code`, `type` and `clntamount` in my table. I want to derive column `clntamount_der`.

[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLEU4.png)

[image]

I want the 110 value in `clntamount` with the `type = Total` to be in the column `clntamount_der` where the `type = base` and the rest two rows(adj and total) as zero.

Please help with the logic.

I tried case statemnt but it didnt work maybe a subquery will work

Comment: does all your data follow the `base` `adjust` `total` ordering?

Comment: yes it does @zhiguang

Comment: can you please not post images because it is not possible to search for the text content.  could you please post the table as text?

Comment: instructions are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Comment: Thank you how will the query change if the table structure is

Comment: @ahmed 's answer seems more general please have a look as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the conditional max window function as the following:

```
select t.*, 
  case 
    when TYPE = 'BASE' 
       then max(case when TYPE = 'TOTAL' then CLNTAMOUNT end) over
               (partition by YearMonth, Code)
       else 0
    end as clntamount_der
from tbl t
order by 
  YearMonth, Code,
  case TYPE
    when 'BASE' then 1
    when 'ADJUST' then 2
    when 'TOTAL' then 3
  end
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GdpZX_EI)

Also, it seems that the `TOTAL` is the sum of other types (BASE, ADJUST), in this case, it would be better to calculate the `TOTAL` on the fly (and not store it as a separate row) to avoid data inconsistency. i.e. when you update the `CLNTAMOUNT` value where `type = 'BASE'` how would you reflect this to the value where `type = 'TOTAL'`?

consider the following without having the `TOTAL` type stored in the table.

```
select d.*
  from
(
  select t.YearMonth, t.Code, t.Type, t.CLNTAMOUNT,
    case 
      when TYPE = 'BASE' 
         then sum(t.CLNTAMOUNT) over (partition by t.YearMonth, t.Code)
         else 0
      end as clntamount_der
  from tbl t
  
  union all
  
  select t.YearMonth, t.Code, 'TOTAL',
          sum(t.CLNTAMOUNT), 0 
  from tbl t
  group by t.YearMonth, t.Code
) d
order by 
  d.YearMonth, d.Code,
  case d.TYPE
    when 'BASE' then 1
    when 'ADJUST' then 2
    when 'TOTAL' then 3
  end
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GMvpUhOF)

Comment: Hi Ahmad the table already has the total type. |YearMonth |Code |TYPE   |CLNTAMOUNT| 
   
|202005    |    ABC |  TOTAL  | 110
|202005    |    XYZ |  TOTAL  |  220
|202005    |   ABC |  BASE   | 100
|202005    |    XYZ |  BASE   | 200
|202005    |   ABC |  ADJUST | 10
|202005    |   XYZ |  ADJUST | 20
 I have 50 codes with total type followed by base and then adjust

Comment: Try the first query, it will cover this case.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible with `case` statement and `lead()` function

```
select *, case when TYPE = 'BASE' then lead(clntamount,2)
over (order by (select null)) else 0 end as clntamount_der
from test
```

see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I3x6ViHY) here

Comment: The `order by (select null)` will not guarantee that the second row after the BASE is TOTAL, check this  https://dbfiddle.uk/ZyHTnzY0

Comment: Also, would this SQL Server syntax be valid on Oracle?

Comment: hi @ahmed yes although for the OP's data it seems to be acceptable

Comment: It worked in your fiddle just by chance! As you can see in the fiddle I posted when you change the order of the inserted data the query gives incorrect output.

Comment: @ahmed yes though this depends on the OP's data that i asked about, your solution is more general, thanks

Comment: |YearMonth |Code |TYPE   |CLNTAMOUNT| 
|----------|--------|---------|----------|        
|202005    |    ABC |  TOTAL  | 110 
|202005    |    XYZ |  TOTAL  | 220 
|202005    |   ABC |  BASE   | 100 
|202005    |    XYZ |  BASE   | 200 
|202005    |   ABC |  ADJUST | 10 
|202005    |   XYZ |  ADJUST | 20                                                                    
 Thank you @zhiguang I have like 50 codes in the following layout total first followed by base and then adjust. Your solution is perfect but I am not able to change the syntax for the above layout for 50 codes

Comment: @TejasMagar yes you can look at @ahmed 's solution because he `order by` the `TYPE` in his query